# Using babel-cli locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

Is there a way to use the babel client without installing it globally?

So rather than this

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

I'd like to do this

```
npm install babel-cli --save-dev
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any local package's binary can be accessed inside [*npm scripts*](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as if it was installed globally:

```
// package.json
{
   "scripts": {
     "build": "babel ..."
   }
}
```

If you want to execute the binary on the command line, you can use a relative path to `node_modules/.bin/`:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/babel ...
```

This is related to first example: `node_modules/.bin/` is simple added to the PATH of the environment the npm scripts are executed in.

Comment: This is the output in the terminal. `The CLI has been moved into the package "babel-cli". $ npm install -g babel-cli `

Comment: @ZackArgyle: Have you install `babel-cli` locally? You may have to reference the binary directly via `node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js`.

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/get-iterator'`

Comment: Seems like your installation is corrupt. Remove `node_modules/` and install everything again (note: this is unrelated to your question).

Answer (score 2):

you can put something like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "start": "babel-node test.js"
  }
}
```

in your `package.json` where `test.js` is a script which you want to run. Now you can run it with `npm start` command

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could install locally and run from `node_modules`:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel
```

If you have a local package.json you could add an NPM [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to simplify the command, since NPM scripts run with `./node_modules/.bin` on the `PATH`:

```
"scripts": {
  "babel": "babel ...",
}
```

To run from any directory under package.json:

```
$ npm run babel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run test with command "npm test testFile.js". This is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel-node",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/babel-node"
}
```